# spring batch use data source instead of jdbc using batch-db2.properties

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am fairly new to spring batch. I have it working embedded inside my spring mvc web application. It is using a db2 database data store to log job information. At present my batch-db2.properties reads as...

```
batch.jdbc.driver=com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
batch.jdbc.url=<<my database url>>
batch.jdbc.user=<<my database user>>
batch.jdbc.password=<<my database password>>
batch.schema=<<my database scehma>>
batch.jndi.name=jdbc/<<my jndi url>>
```

So I've set both jdbc properties and well as the jndi property. The jobs are running fine but my question is what type of connection is my spring batch installation using.

If both are set does it use jdbc or jndi? Also can someone point me to the spring batch documentation page where it gives more information about these settings. I could not find it.

Here is my data source configuration....

```
<beans profile="server">     

    <bean id="ePosDataSource" 
        class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean"
        p:jndiName="java:comp/env/jdbc/reportingManagerDataSource"
        p:lookupOnStartup="false"
        p:cache="true"
        p:proxyInterface="javax.sql.DataSource"/>

    <jee:jndi-lookup id="ePosDataSource"
        jndi-name="jdbc/reportingManagerDataSource"
        cache="true"
        resource-ref="true"
        lookup-on-startup="false"
        proxy-interface="javax.sql.DataSource"/>    

    <bean id="custDbDataSource" 
        class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean"
        p:jndiName="java:comp/env/jdbc/reportingManagerCustDbDataSource"
        p:lookupOnStartup="false"
        p:cache="true"
        p:proxyInterface="javax.sql.DataSource" />          

    <jee:jndi-lookup id="custDbDataSource"
        jndi-name="jdbc/reportingManagerCustDbDataSource"
        cache="true"
        resource-ref="true"
        lookup-on-startup="false"
        proxy-interface="javax.sql.DataSource"/>                            
</beans>
```

thanks!

Comment: Can you add how you configured your `DataSource`?

Comment: You've coded all of the properties in the bean definitions so those values in the properties files aren't being used at all in most likelihood.  However, I have a hard time believing the above configuration is your actual configuration since you have two definitions with the same id (that should blow up on startup).

Comment: Thanks Michael. I picked up that configuration off a blog somewhere and it is working for me. This is definitely my configuration that I am using in production. So are you sauing that the bean definition and the jndi lookup are duplicates? I thought I needed both there. There are different properties defined in each.

Comment: Spring Contexts only provide one bean definition per id.  In your case, which ever one is parsed second would overwrite the first one I believe.  I'd remove the ones you don't want (either JDBC of JNDI) and see if that impacts your application (I don't believe it should).